# How do I find the line where the app crashes on SIGABRT errors?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, crash

I am developing a SwiftUI based app in Xcode and when in my LobbyView - my app crashes at different times. There is a host of the lobby and regular players.

The app is hooked up to a realm database and whenever changes are made to the lobby and sent to the database, I inconsistently get a SIGABRT error on the main thread or I get a EXC_Bad_Access error. Here is my crash report, the biggest issue I have is that I cannot locate the line that is causing this crash.

Also, inconsistently crashing at different times makes it way harder to find. Here is my crash report:

```
    frame #0: 0x0000000199617488 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_retain + 8
    frame #1: 0x000000010287f1a8 Hoops`initializeWithCopy for PlayerInLobby at <compiler-generated>:0
    frame #2: 0x00000001889ba00c SwiftUI`SwiftUI.DynamicBody.updateValue() -> () + 476
    frame #3: 0x0000000188a00d28 SwiftUI`partial apply forwarder for implicit closure #2 (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in implicit closure #1 (τ_1_0.Type) -> (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in closure #1 () -> (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in closure #1 (Swift.UnsafePointer<τ_1_0>) -> AttributeGraph.Attribute<τ_0_0> in AttributeGraph.Attribute.init<τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 == τ_1_0.Value, τ_1_0: AttributeGraph.StatefulRule>(τ_1_0) -> AttributeGraph.Attribute<τ_0_0> + 32
    frame #4: 0x00000001b27f29a4 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 532
    frame #5: 0x00000001b27f23ac AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 396
    frame #6: 0x00000001b27f311c AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, unsigned char&, long) + 376
    frame #7: 0x00000001b27f0cd0 AttributeGraph`AGGraphGetValue + 236
    frame #8: 0x0000000188a1d64c SwiftUI`SwiftUI.AnimatableFrameAttribute.updateValue() -> () + 56
    frame #9: 0x0000000188a71ff8 SwiftUI`partial apply forwarder for generic specialization <SwiftUI.ViewFrame, SwiftUI.AnimatableFrameAttribute> of implicit closure #2 (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in implicit closure #1 (τ_1_0.Type) -> (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in closure #1 () -> (Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer, __C.AGAttribute) -> () in closure #1 (Swift.UnsafePointer<τ_1_0>) -> AttributeGraph.Attribute<τ_0_0> in AttributeGraph.Attribute.init<τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 == τ_1_0.Value, τ_1_0: AttributeGraph.StatefulRule>(τ_1_0) -> AttributeGraph.Attribute<τ_0_0> + 24
    frame #10: 0x00000001b27f29a4 AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 532
    frame #11: 0x00000001b27f23ac AttributeGraph`AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 396
    frame #12: 0x00000001b27f11f4 AttributeGraph`AG::Subgraph::update(unsigned int) + 968
    frame #13: 0x0000000188978bec SwiftUI`SwiftUI.GraphHost.flushTransactions() -> () + 412
    frame #14: 0x00000001895ec5b8 SwiftUI`closure #1 (SwiftUI.GraphHost) -> () in closure #1 () -> () in closure #1 () -> () in SwiftUI.GraphHost.asyncTransaction<τ_0_0 where τ_0_0: SwiftUI.GraphMutation>(_: SwiftUI.Transaction, mutation: τ_0_0, style: SwiftUI._GraphMutation_Style, mayDeferUpdate: Swift.Bool) -> () + 24
    frame #15: 0x000000018896a830 SwiftUI`partial apply forwarder for closure #1 (SwiftUI.ViewGraph) -> τ_1_0 in SwiftUI.ViewGraphDelegate.updateGraph<τ_0_0>(body: (SwiftUI.GraphHost) -> τ_1_0) -> τ_1_0 + 28
    frame #16: 0x00000001889760ac SwiftUI`closure #1 () -> τ_1_0 in SwiftUI.ViewRendererHost.updateViewGraph<τ_0_0>(body: (SwiftUI.ViewGraph) -> τ_1_0) -> τ_1_0 + 108
    frame #17: 0x000000018896eed8 SwiftUI`SwiftUI.ViewRendererHost.updateViewGraph<τ_0_0>(body: (SwiftUI.ViewGraph) -> τ_1_0) -> τ_1_0 + 96
    frame #18: 0x0000000188968304 SwiftUI`SwiftUI.ViewGraphDelegate.updateGraph<τ_0_0>(body: (SwiftUI.GraphHost) -> τ_1_0) -> τ_1_0 + 84
    frame #19: 0x0000000188967390 SwiftUI`merged closure #1 () -> () in SwiftUI.GraphHost.init(data: SwiftUI.GraphHost.Data) -> SwiftUI.GraphHost + 156
    frame #20: 0x0000000188a726d0 SwiftUI`reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () to @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> (@out ()) + 28
    frame #21: 0x00000001889658dc SwiftUI`static __C.NSRunLoop.flushObservers() -> () + 152
    frame #22: 0x0000000188965954 SwiftUI`closure #1 () -> () in closure #1 (Swift.Optional<__C.CFRunLoopObserverRef>, __C.CFRunLoopActivity, Swift.Optional<Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer>) -> () in static __C.NSRunLoop.addObserver(() -> ()) -> () + 16
    frame #23: 0x0000000188a53a04 SwiftUI`function signature specialization <Arg[1] = [Constant Propagated Function : closure #1 () -> () in closure #1 (Swift.Optional<__C.CFRunLoopObserverRef>, __C.CFRunLoopActivity, Swift.Optional<Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer>) -> () in static (extension in SwiftUI):__C.NSRunLoop.addObserver(() -> ()) -> ()]> of reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_guaranteed () -> (@error @owned Swift.Error) to @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> (@out (), @error @owned Swift.Error) + 24
    frame #24: 0x00000001aec24a20 libswiftObjectiveC.dylib`ObjectiveC.autoreleasepool<τ_0_0>(invoking: () throws -> τ_0_0) throws -> τ_0_0 + 64
    frame #25: 0x00000001889657f4 SwiftUI`closure #1 (Swift.Optional<__C.CFRunLoopObserverRef>, __C.CFRunLoopActivity, Swift.Optional<Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer>) -> () in static __C.NSRunLoop.addObserver(() -> ()) -> () + 64
    frame #26: 0x0000000188965ac4 SwiftUI`@objc closure #1 (Swift.Optional<__C.CFRunLoopObserverRef>, __C.CFRunLoopActivity, Swift.Optional<Swift.UnsafeMutableRawPointer>) -> () in static __C.NSRunLoop.addObserver(() -> ()) -> () + 56
    frame #27: 0x0000000180f5d560 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36
    frame #28: 0x0000000180f2c844 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 572
    frame #29: 0x0000000180f278dc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1052
    frame #30: 0x0000000180f3b3b8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
    frame #31: 0x000000019c8cb38c GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 164
    frame #32: 0x00000001838db6a8 UIKitCore`-[UIApplication _run] + 1100
    frame #33: 0x000000018365a7f4 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 2092
    frame #34: 0x0000000188b9e258 SwiftUI`closure #1 (Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Optional<Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Int8>>>) -> Swift.Never in SwiftUI.KitRendererCommon(Swift.AnyObject.Type) -> Swift.Never + 164
    frame #35: 0x0000000188acc534 SwiftUI`SwiftUI.runApp<τ_0_0 where τ_0_0: SwiftUI.App>(τ_0_0) -> Swift.Never + 252
    frame #36: 0x0000000188aadcb4 SwiftUI`static SwiftUI.App.main() -> () + 128
  * frame #37: 0x0000000102990600 Hoops`static HoopsSUIApp.$main(self=Hoops.HoopsSUIApp) at HoopsApp.swift:13:1
    frame #38: 0x00000001029906ac Hoops`main at HoopsApp.swift:0
    frame #39: 0x0000000106939a24 dyld`start + 520
```

My biggest issue with this is not being able to find the line where it crashes. I've set exception breakpoints and they do not get triggered during the crash. When the app crashes it takes me to the file that has the @main symbol.

Anybody have any clues for me as far as why the app is crashing or how to locate the exact line of the point of crashing? Thanks.

Comment: Did you put breakpoint in your attribute graph : seems that code calls is looping : graph - swift ui - graph same line

Comment: @matt this is good info for me I didn’t realize how early PlayerInLobby was being created in the app. Let me do some more debugging and see if I can pinpoint it